Doesn't include the summary of chat history in the chat memory by langchain ConversationSummaryBufferMemory
I'm using a chatbot which is created by python langchain. In that I'm sending requests to the several LLM models (OPENAI , Claude, GEMINI). When I send requests to llm, first I summarize my previous chat. For summarize it I send my previous chats with a prompt mentioning to summarize this chat. It is done by ConversationSummaryBufferMemory using llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name=GPT3_MODEL) . By then I got that summary of the chat history and I stored it in a variable. After when I send my query to the LLM, I send it with the prompt , query and the summery of chat history that I have stored in a variable. But in the verbose I can see whole the chat history in the prompt instead of the summery of the previous chat.
    def __set_chain_memory(self, user_id, conversation_id):
        chat_mem = self.chat_memory.get(user_id, conversation_id)
        llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name=GPT3_MODEL)
        self.chain_memory = ConversationSummaryBufferMemory(
            llm=llm,
            chat_memory=chat_mem,
            memory_key="history",
            input_key="query",
            return_messages=True,
            max_token_limit=1000,
        )
        self.chain_memory.prune()

chain_memory is the variable that I store the summery of the chat. chat_mem is the whole previous chat that I get from the postgres database.
    def generate_streaming_llm_response(
        self,
        user_id: str,
        conversation_id: str,
        user_input,
        llm,
        prompt: str,
        callback_handler: StreamingHandler,
    ):
        self.__set_chain_memory(user_id, conversation_id)

        chain = StreamingChain(
            llm=llm,
            prompt=prompt,
            memory=self.chain_memory,
            queue_manager=callback_handler.queue_manager,
        )

        return chain.stream(user_input, callback_handler.queue_id)

after I send the summery of chat memory in to the StreamingChain to generate the response .
class StreamingChain(LLMChain):
    queue_manager = QueueManager()

    def __init__(self, llm, prompt, memory, queue_manager):
        super().__init__(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, memory=memory)
        self.queue_manager = queue_manager

    def stream(self, input, queue_id, **kwargs):
        queue = self.queue_manager.get_queue(queue_id)

        def task():
            try:
                self(input)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(f"Exception caught")
                self.queue_manager.close_queue(queue_id)

        t = Thread(target=task)
        t.start()

        try:
            while True:
                token = queue.get()
                if token is None:
                    break
                yield token
        finally:
            t.join()
            self.queue_manager.close_queue(queue_id)

I want to send the summery of the previous chat to generate the response from the LLM.
